# HTML ETags and Github Pages

Tags: html, github, pagespeed, etag

I am taking a course at Udacity and we are learning about the caching system that the ETags provide:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

I am using GitHub pages, and from an answer in the forums:

- http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100195399/optimized-portfolios/100196340

I have the distinct idea that I **cannot use ETags** to optimize my page's load speed.

Is this true? If not, how can I do it? I am completely lost here and would appreciate any possible help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sent and e-mail to GitHub's support and this is still not possible. The answer was clear and concise:

> This isn't possible, however I'll give this a +1 on our internal
>   Feature Request List. We can't promise if we may add something like
>   this, however your feedback is appreciated.

Special thanks to James Dennes for the quick answer.